# How should I improve the wiring in this light fixture junction box?

Tags: wiring, safety, light

Is it legal for blind people to wire a ceiling rose? I mean, it's the only reason I can imagine this happened

[image]

Jokes aside, the light is actually functioning as is. I only discovered this when I was going to replace the fitting with a nicer one. Should I:

A) wire the new one in properly, email the previous owner and call him an idiot (again)

B) call an electrician because who knows what's actually going on in there

C) just move out and give up on anything in this house having been wired correctly

Answers on a postcard friends.

Comment: -1 To my knowledge, there is nothing that discredits an otherwise qualified person to do wiring due to blindness. However, disguising a rant as a question does fall outside the spirit of stack exchange. If you have an actual question, please consider rephrasing it to ask for primarily non-opinion-based advice as per the site rules (refer to the help center: https://diy.stackexchange.com/help for further details)

Comment: I agree, but I tried to salvage it. OP can make further improvements.

Answer (score 1):

D) Grab a book and a roll of brown electrical tape, learn to wire British style, and go through every connection in the whole house and fix them all.

It's between you and your council whether "repair" requires a permit/inspection/professional etc.

Once you've done that, get RCD protection... I can tell you don't have it now.